# How to make changes in Magento accessshop theme UI

Tags: css, user-interface, magento, magento-1.9

I am a beginner in magento development. Recently I started a new project ideabaz. 
It is available at

- http://104.155.38.124

I tried learning about directory structure of magento but unable to resolve it.
These are some issues which i want to resolve:

1. I want to resize searchbox and move it to center.
2. Remove horizontal lines in header & remove top navigation bar.

Kindly suggest me , how can i make these changes.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try locating the styles with Developer Tools (F12), after that you can overwrite the CSS to how you want it to be. Make a new CSS style and require it as last within your `<head></head>`.